# Add 2 condition for for loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go

I am using to arrays which might be differnet length.
I want to compare elements.
So I need check smallest length of array store it in var & then have to use that var in for loop.

To avoid this I want to check this lenth in for loop
like

```
for i:=0; (i<len(arr1)&&(i<len(arr2)) ; i++{
        if arr1[i] < arr2[i] {}
}
```

OR

```
for i:=0; true == (i<len(arr1)&&(i<len(arr2)) ; i++{
        if arr1[i] < arr2[i] {}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what's the question or does the above code throw any error?

Comment: The second variant is nonsense. `true == x` is equivalent to `x` and the later much clearer and shorter.

Comment: All the extra `()` make you code a lot harder to read. `for i:=0; i<len(arr1) && i<len(arr2); i++` IMO.

Answer (score 0):

you could precompute which slice is longer

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func longest(l1 []int, l2 []int) int {
    if len(l1) > len(l2) {
        return len(l2)
    }
    return len(l1)
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 46, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 99, 87, 34}
    b := []int{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    maxlen := longest(a, b)
    for i := 0; i < maxlen; i++ {
        if a[i] > b[i] {
            fmt.Printf("%d yes", i)
        }
    }

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/SXUwKrQrEo2